# "Inline" border of a div

Tags: css

This is what I want to archive:

[image: A green Block with text inside and a kind of inline border]

This is my code:

```css
.mybox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #00483b;
  /* ... and other simple stuff border: THIS IS MY PROBLEM */
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">Text Inside</div>
```

How can I draw a white border around my div? This border should be some pixels inside the box. I am pretty sure that I have seen something like that or am I wrong and that is not possible? How should I proceed then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `outline`, which draws an additional border *outside* of the normal `border`.

```css
.mybox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #00483b;
  border: 1px solid white;
  outline: 3px solid #00483b;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">Text Inside</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a white border on the div and then use the box-shadow property to give the second outer border

```css
.mybox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #00483b;
  border:1px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #00483b;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">Text Inside</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution.

```css
.mybox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #00483b;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: 3px solid #00483b;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight:600;
  letter-spacing:1px;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">Text Inside</div>
```

Check This Solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use multiple `box-shadow`s

```css
.mybox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #00483b;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 4px #00483b;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">Text Inside</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `:after` pseudo element to create border.

```css
.mybox {
  background: #00483B;
  padding: 20px 45px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.mybox:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">Text Inside</div>
```